# Quantum entropy Venn diagrams

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, it.information-theory, quantum-mechanics

We know that in classical information theory the relation between different entropies can be depicted by Venn Diagram as given below.

[image]

Can we create such Venn-diagrams for the quantum information theory case, where we consider Von-Neumann Entropy? I feel such Venn diagrams are not possible because in Quantum Information, some entropies can be negative. What can we do in such a scenario. Is there any research being performed in this direction, to create a geometrical picture of quantum information theory?

Comment: Even for three discrete random variables, the central region in the Venn diagram may represent a negative entropy. See for instance 8.31 in MacKay's book: https://www.inference.org.uk/itprnn/book.pdf.

Comment: @Mark Wildon Thanks, I did not know that the representation of entropies in terms of Venn diagrams is misleading. A lot of books on Quantum Information follow this approach of using Venn Diagrams, also a lot of them do not consider 3 random variables. I had not read this book so I did not know about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional entropies can be negative, so the sign is not an issue here. An introduction to quantum Venn diagrams that you may like is given by [Chris Adami](https://adami.natsci.msu.edu/blog/2014/11/11/on-quantum-measurement-part-5-quantum-venn-diagrams). Here is an example of a quantum system Q measured by a classical measurement device A that consists of two pieces $A_1$ and $A_2$. The shared information (central region) is always zero, which is what prevents cloning of a quantum state.

[image]